# How can I distribute decryption keys to servers?

Tags: gratis, linux, open-source, encryption

I'm trying to implement user-folder encryption (as opposed to full-disk encryption) on some Linux servers in a data center. I don't want to store the decryption key in plain text on the servers because that would render the encryption useless if the servers were stolen.

I've found mentions of an off-site key server which would send a decryption key to servers, but only if the requests came from a certain IP range (that of the data center):

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/89825/is-full-disk-encryption-on-a-server-in-a-secure-data-center-pointless

but I can't seem to find any implementations of such a key server. I've had a go at doing it myself using things like wget, but I'd rather offload some of the responsibility to someone who knows a lot more about security than I do, by using some off-the-shelf.

My thinking is that this key server software would reside on another server in another data center which would use full-disk encryption and would require a password at boot. This other server will probably be located in our office so that's something I'm willing to accept.

Is there any (FLOSS) software that does what I want?

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for [Vormetric](http://www.vormetric.com/products/transparent-encryption).

Comment: @gowenfawr - thanks! That looks like it costs money, I'd rather something open source and free.

Comment: I don't think you're going to find a FLOSS equivalent although, of course, you're welcome to roll your own.